# sigma.js - An object called sigma is already in the global scope

Tags: javascript, sigma.js

I am new to sigma js and trying to draw a basic graph using the beginners examples provided online. My graph got displayed just once and post that each time I run the code I get the following error:

> Uncaught An object called sigma is already in the global scope

My code looks like:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src='js_use/sigma.js'></script>
    <script src = 'js_use/sigma.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js_use/sigma.utils.js'></script>
    <script src = 'js_use/sigma.parsers.json.min.js'></script>
    <script src = 'js_use/sigma.require.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id = "container"> </div>
    <script>

 g = {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "id": "node_apple",
      "label": "Apple_Inc.",
      "x": 10,
      "y": 8,
      "size": 5
    },
    {
      "id": "node_steve_jobs",
      "label": "Steve_Jobs",
      "x": 14,
      "y": 8,
      "size": 5
    },
    {
      "id": "node_public_company",
      "label": "Public_Company",
      "x": 7,
      "y": 5,
      "size": 2
    }
  ],
  "edges": [
    {
      "id": "e0",
      "source": "node_apple",
      "target": "node_steve_jobs"
    },
    {
      "id": "e1",
      "source": "node_apple",
      "target": "node_public_company"
    },
    {
      "id": "e2",
      "source": "node_steve_jobs",
      "target": "node_apple"
    }
  ]
}

const s=new sigma({
    graph : g,
    container : 'container'
});

s.refresh();


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Excuse me if its some silly error. I have just started out and have been grappling with this for quite sometime. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have added `sigma.js` and `sigma.min.js`. Try removing one of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've imported Sigma twice, once here:

```
<script src='js_use/sigma.js'></script>
```

And once here:

```
<script src = 'js_use/sigma.min.js'></script>
```

The one with `.min.` in it is a minified file. It has exactly the same content as the other, but its compressed so that it will load faster. Generally speaking, you want the 'production-ready' version of your website to load minified files. The flip side is that the minified files can be harder to debug, as they remove some of the information that is useful to you as a developer, but doesn't actually affect how the program behaves. Feel free to keep either one of them, get rid of the other.